# how to write a json in middle of union functionality throwing error

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, postgresql-9.3, pgadmin

I wrote a union function in the middle of union wrote a json object is one of the parameter, but throwing error : **could not identify an equality operator for type json**. Here is my code.

```
select(SELECT array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(resdt))) FROM 
                        (select  vt.task_id,vp.project_name,vp.status as project_status,
                 vt.project_id,vt.task_description,vt.planned_start_date,vt.planned_end_date,
        (select array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(b))) FROM   
         (select vl.* 
            from  public."VOfficeApp_task" vat
            inner join public."VOfficeApp_task_labels" vtl on vat.task_id = vtl.task_id
            inner join  public."VOfficeApp_labels" vl on  vl.label_id = vtl.label_id
            where vl.status = true
            and vat.task_id = vt.task_id
     )b)as label_name,
        
             (select array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(b))) FROM
                     (select tr.task_resource_id,tr.task_id,tr.project_resource_id ,
                             tr.assigned_date,tr.assigned_by,pr.employee_id as id,
                             concat(u.first_name,u.last_name) as employeename
                             from public."VOfficeApp_task" vtr
                             inner join public."VOfficeApp_project_resources" pr on pr.project_id = vtr.project_id
                             inner join public."VOfficeApp_task_resource" tr on tr.project_resource_id = pr.project_resource_id
                             and tr.task_id = vt.task_id
                             inner join public."VOfficeApp_user" u on u.id =pr.employee_id
                             where tr.released_date is null and vtr.task_id =vt.task_id
                             and vtr.status != 'Delete')b)as user_name,
    (select count(task_id)from  public."VOfficeApp_task" ptra
                     where  ptra.task_id = vt.task_id
                     and status = 'Assigned')Active_count,


                 from public."VOfficeApp_task" vt 
                 inner join public."VOfficeApp_projects" vp on vt.project_id = vp.project_id
                 inner join public."VOfficeApp_task_resource" vtr on vt.task_id = vtr.task_id
                 inner join  public."VOfficeApp_project_resources" vpr on vtr.project_resource_id = vpr.project_resource_id
                 left join public."VOfficeApp_conversation" cvv on cvv.projtaskid = vt.task_id
                
                 where vp.company_id = companyid 
                 and vp.created_by = createdby
                 and vt.status != 'Delete'    
                --order by vt.task_id desc
```

union
select  vt.task_id,vp.project_name,vp.status as project_status,
vt.project_id,vt.task_description,vt.planned_start_date,vt.planned_end_date,

```
      (select array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(b))) FROM
         (select vl.* 
            from  public."VOfficeApp_task" vat
            inner join public."VOfficeApp_task_labels" vtl on vat.task_id = vtl.task_id
            inner join  public."VOfficeApp_labels" vl on  vl.label_id = vtl.label_id
            where vl.status = true
            and vat.task_id = vt.task_id
     )b)as label_name,
                         (select array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(b))) FROM
                     (select tr.task_resource_id,tr.task_id,tr.project_resource_id ,
                             tr.assigned_date,tr.assigned_by,pr.employee_id as id,
                             concat(u.first_name,u.last_name) as employeename
                             from public."VOfficeApp_task" vtr
                             inner join public."VOfficeApp_project_resources" pr on pr.project_id = vtr.project_id
                             inner join public."VOfficeApp_task_resource" tr on tr.project_resource_id = pr.project_resource_id
                             and tr.task_id = vt.task_id
                             inner join public."VOfficeApp_user" u on u.id =pr.employee_id
                             where tr.released_date is null and vtr.task_id =vt.task_id
                             and vtr.status != 'Delete')b)as user_name,
         
                    from public."VOfficeApp_task" vt 
                    inner join public."VOfficeApp_projects" vp on vt.project_id = vp.project_id
                    inner join public."VOfficeApp_task_resource" vtr on vt.task_id = vtr.task_id
                    inner join  public."VOfficeApp_project_resources" vpr on vtr.project_resource_id = vpr.project_resource_id
                    --inner join public."VOfficeApp_user" u on u.id =vpr.employee_id
                    where vp.company_id = companyid and vpr.employee_id = createdby
                    and  vt.status != 'Delete'  
                    --order by vt.task_id desc
                         
                )resdt)as My_tasks;
```

Answer (score 0):

As the message implies, json doesn't define an equality operator, and one of those is needed to implement the deduplication feature of UNION.  And json doesn't canonicalize its value, so its not clear what an unambiguous definition of equality would even be.  Should '{"a":"b","c":"d"}' be considered different from '{"c":"d","a":"b"}'?

You can upgrade to a supported version of the database, then use jsonb rather than json.  This does define an equality operator, and treats the two examples above as being the same.

You could change UNION to UNION ALL, if dedup is not essential to you.

You can cast the json to text in each of the SELECT.  That treats the two example as being different.